# Unable to remove cordova plugins from Ionic

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, ionic5

I am not able to remove any plugins from cordova. It breaks down when I install cordova-firebase-plugin in android.

```
> cordova plugin remove cordova-plugin-firebase
Uninstalling cordova-plugin-firebase from android
Error during processing of action! Attempting to revert...
Uh oh!
ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/home/abhishek/client_projects/scrabily/platforms/android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml'
```

Ionic Info

```
Ionic:

   Ionic CLI                     : 6.1.0 (/usr/lib/node_modules/@ionic/cli)
   Ionic Framework               : @ionic/angular 5.0.0
   @angular-devkit/build-angular : 0.803.24
   @angular-devkit/schematics    : 8.1.3
   @angular/cli                  : 8.1.3
   @ionic/angular-toolkit        : 2.1.2

Cordova:

   Cordova CLI       : 9.0.0 (cordova-lib@9.0.1)
   Cordova Platforms : android 8.1.0, browser 6.0.0
   Cordova Plugins   : cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard 2.2.0, cordova-plugin-ionic-webview 4.1.3, (and 14 other plugins)

Utility:

   cordova-res : 0.9.0
   native-run  : 0.3.0

System:

   Android SDK Tools : 26.1.1 (/home/abhishek/Android/Sdk)
   NodeJS            : v12.8.0 (/usr/bin/node)
   npm               : 6.13.7
   OS                : Linux 5.3
```

List of cordova plugins, installed in my project

```
abhishek@hubroot:~/client_projects/scrabily$ ionic cordova plugin ls
> cordova plugin ls
cordova-plugin-firebase 2.0.5 "Google Firebase Plugin"
cordova-plugin-firebasex 7.0.2 "Google Firebase Plugin"
```

Here is some excerpt of plugins. I am not able to remove any of these cordova plugins.

Comment: removing and adding the platform often fixes those kinds of problems.

Comment: I had done similar things, but the trick work for me is ,  remove platform first, then remove plugin.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It works by removing platform first, then removing the plugin.

```
ionic cordova platfrom rm android
ionic cordova plugin remove cordova-plugin-firebase
```